# jQuery Slider Maintain Value on Postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using a jQuery UI slider without any troubles other than this: I have an ASP.NET hidden field that stores whatever the user selected with the slider. Say 25, or 50. I need that server control so that I can use its value after other steps are performed. It works but when the page does the postback, the slider reverts to where it originally was. In other words, the user selects 50 on the slider, the post to the server goes and retrieves 50 records. But the slider goes back to 25 as that was its initial value. How do I fix this so that it keeps the setting stored in the hidden field control (or what the user selected)?

I have added the code here:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //setup slider
        $('#slider').slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 25,
            step: 25,
            max: 100,
            value: 75,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $('#radiusText').val(ui.value);
                //set the hiddenfield for server postback of radius
                $("#<%= Radius.ClientID%>").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $('#radiusText').val($('#slider').slider('value'));


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up setting a variable outside of the slider call that gets the value of the hiddenfield and set that initial value to 75 on the hiddenfield.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var setRadius = $("#<%= Radius.ClientID%>").val();
        //setup slider
        $('#slider').slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 25,
            step: 25,
            max: 100,
            value: setRadius,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $('#radiusText').val(ui.value);
                //set the hiddenfield for server postback of radius
                $("#<%= Radius.ClientID%>").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $('#radiusText').val($('#slider').slider('value'));
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the ispostback property of ASP pages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

```
public string _hiddenvalue; //make it public so that you can read it
if(ispostback)
{
  _hiddenvalue = Request.Form["hiddenfield"];              
}
```

then all you have to do is assign the public property _hiddenvalue to a variable in your front side

```
var _slideVal = <%= _hiddenvalue %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SetSlider()
    {   
              $('#slider').slider({
                    range: "max",
                    min: 25,
                    step: 25,
                    max: 100,
                    value: 75,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#radiusText').val(ui.value);
                        //set the hiddenfield for server postback of radius
                        $("#<%= Radius.ClientID%>").val(ui.value);
                    }
                });
    }
```

On server side, On PageLoad Event call javascript function.

```
if(!ispostback)
{
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript",
   "javascript:SetSlider();", true);
}
```

let me know if i doesn't understand your problem very well.